# Writing multiple tables to FROM line in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

In SELECT line I use array() for multiple data column retrieval.
In WHERE line I can simple concat strings.
That is clear till now.
However I could not find any documentation about giving multiple table name in FROM line. All documentations are usage of join which is scary for me.

I am using this structure for building queries.

```
$query->select(array(foo1,foo2));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__footable'); ??? $_footable2 ???
$query->where($db->quoteName('fooname')." = ".$db->quote($foodata));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fabian is right that we need to know what data you want, with what structure and what you want to do with it. That will help determine if a JOIN, UNION, subquery or something else is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do a JOIN.  Here's an example grabbing all articles in a specific category, arbitrarily chosen as category id of 3, as well as the category title, all in one query.

```
$query->select('a.id, a.catid, a.title');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content') . ' AS a');
$query->select('c.title as category');
$query->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__categories') . ' AS c ON c.id = a.catid');
$query->where('a.catid = 3');
```

Notice the addition of 'a.' and 'c.' to identify which table any field name is referencing.  I would highly recommend reviewing any of the core MVC path model classes, specifically the getListQuery() methods as they will be loaded with JOIN examples using the Joomla framework.

Answer (score 0):

The recommend way to put multiple tables in the from clause of a SQL is a join.  I would suggest you learn how to use join statements as they are useful and essential for making more complex SQL database queries.  Check this link out: [Tutorial on SQL Joins](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp)

If you want to select from two tables in SQL, that means you have two tables that are linked together and you want to combine one row from one table with a row from another table and get a result that has columns from each table. For instance, your code would look something like:

```
$query->select(array('#_footable.foo1', '#_footable2.foo2');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#_footbale'));
$query->join($db->quoteName('#_footbale2') . ' on ' $db->quoteName('#_footbale') . '.foo1 == ' . $db->quoteName('#_footbale2') '.foo1');
$query->where($db->quoteName('fooname')." = ".$db->quote($foodata));
```

What you have put up suggests that you have two tables with the same signature and you want to get them back in the same result.  If this is the case, then you need to restructure your database.  There is no need to have two tables with the same signature.  Combine footable2 into footable.  If you need to distinguish between the two, then create another column in footable to distinguish between the two.

Elin reminded me that there is the UNION clause in SQL.  So I added this extra vit to the solution which is a bit cleaner:

If you absolutely need to have two tables with the same signature, you could use the `union` function in Joomla.  Your code would be:

```
$query->select(array(foo1,foo2)); 
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__footable'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('fooname')." = ".$db->quote($foodata));

$query2->select(array(foo1,foo2));
$query2->from($db->quoteName('#__footable2'));
$query2->where($db->quoteName('fooname')." = ".$db->quote($foodata));

$query->union($query2);
```

I hope that helps

Comment: You can use UNION so "no way" is not exactly correct but I agree it's in principle true.